# In yii application How to insert data which is fetched from another table into current table

Tags: database, yii

I have two tables in database namely QbQuestion(Qid,Question,StatusId) and Qbstatus(StatusId,Status),,,,,where Status stores status as new,acive,inactive etc.
i want to fetch StatusOptions on view form of QbQuestion in form of dropdownBox. i got succeded to fetch StatusOptions on QbQuestion view form but that selected entry is not getting inserted in QbQuestion table. In _form.php,to fetch StatusOptions, i have inserted code as follows:
    labelEx(Qbstatus::model(),'Status'); ?>
        findAll();
    $list = CHtml::listData($records,'QuestionStatusId', 'Status');
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('Qbstatus', null, $list, array('empty' => 'Select a Status'));
    ?>
    error(QbStatus::model(),'Status'); ?>

So what i should do in order to make entries in QbQuestion table

Comment: update your question with code from your controller, namely the create action

Comment: Thanx for helping me.Here is my controller's actioncreate method. public function actionCreate()
 {
  $model=new Qbquestion;
  $model1=new Qbstatus;

  // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
  // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

  if(isset($_POST['Qbquestion']))
  {
   $model->attributes=$_POST['Qbquestion'];
   $model1->Language=$_POST['QbStatus'];
   if($model->save()&& $model1->save())
    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->QuestionId));
  }

  $this->render('create',array(
   'model'=>$model,
  ));
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but from what I understand you are unable to make the drop down list display the correct options/values, which then prevents your QbQuestion table from storing the correct id for the QuestionStatusId?

Here is how your drop down list should look (untested obviously):

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList($model,'StatusId',CHtml::listData(Qbstatus::model()->findAll(),'QuestionStatusId','Status'),array('empty'=>'Select a Status'));
```

If you view the source you should see a normal HTML  structure with Display Value

In your controller/action that receives the form, you should be able to echo out the model value for the StatusId and see there if it is getting passed